# Testing inequalities on lists

Tags: netlogo

I have tried several different ways using different list primitives, but cannot find a way to test an inequality for each item of a list. For example, my list `[1 2 -1 -2]` could be tested for > 0, and give `[1 2 0 0 ]`. Can someone please help with this simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this, depending on the result you want. For your example, you can do:

```
map [ ifelse-value (? > 0) [ ? ] [ 0 ] ] my-list
```

[`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) creates a new list by applying the given reporter task to each item of the given list. If you haven't used [tasks](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks) in NetLogo before, `?` represents the argument to the task. So, in this  case doing:

```
map [ ifelse-value (? > 0) [ ? ] [ 0 ] ] [1 2 -1 -2]
```

basically does:

```
(list ifelse-value (1 > 0) [ 1 ] [ 0 ]
      ifelse-value (2 > 0) [ 2 ] [ 0 ]
      ifelse-value (-1 > 0) [ -1 ] [ 0 ]
      ifelse-value (-2 > 0) [ -2 ] [ 0 ])
```

[`ifelse-value`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse-value) is like `ifelse`, except that it returns the value in the block that runs.

If, you just want to get rid of all items in the list that fail the inequality, you can use [`filter`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter)

```
filter [ ? < 0 ] my-list
```

`map` and `filter` are very powerful reporters, but they can take a little while to master. But, if you need to do something fancy with lists, chances are you can do it with `map`, `filter`, or (in more extreme cases) [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce).